# Run script under OSX _www user account

Tags: macos, bash, php, webserver

I have a small internal for my use only php website which triggers a bash script to do some app signing etc. 
I need that bash script to run some ruby gems. (Security is not important.)

The way I see it, there are two options:

- Setup a ruby environment and install the gem in the _www user account
- Install a web/php server in an existing user account which has the ruby stuff installed

Is it possible to login into the _www account somehow and setup the required environment?

If not, does anyone have tips on where to get a standalone web/php server so I can run it under a user account so I am able to setup the required environment?

Is there an option I missed?

Comment: Why do you assume that the _www based server needs to be the owner of the Ruby gem?  As long as the web server has read (and execute?) permissions, it should be able to access anything anywhere in your filesystem.  For maintenance, though, it's nice to have some relation, so you can add _www and your user account to the same group, and make sure the gem is owned by that group (using `chgrp` after the install, or `newgrp` before).

Comment: Well, the gem also installs other gems and is also dependant on some brew installs. I would have to chgrp a lot of files. I'm afraid that is going to be a long process figuring out which files to modify...

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get my system to do as I want by granting sudo rights to a specific user using the /etc/sudoers file (only modify this file with `sudo visudo` !!)

Now, in my bash script I can run `sudo -u username mybashcommand` without having to enter a password.